# $F$ a field over $\mathbb{Q}$ of dimension $2$, show $a \in F$ satisfies $a^2 - n = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

> Let $F$ be a field with $\Bbb{Q} \subseteq$ $F$. If $F$ considered as a vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$ has dimension 2, show that there exists an element $a \in F$ which is not in $\Bbb{Q}$ which satisfies an equation of the form $a^2 - n = 0$ for some non-zero integer $n$. Conclude that $F$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{n}]$. Show further that we may assume that if $p$ is a prime that divides $n$, then $p^2$ does not divide $n$.

Honestly, I don't even know where to start here. The only part I understand is why $F$ would be isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{n}]$, but I have no idea how to show the second or the last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** Choose some $b\in F\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Since $F$ is a $2$-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, the three elements $1,b,b^2$ must be $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly dependent, say
$$x\cdot 1 + y\cdot b+z\cdot b^2 =0,\qquad\text{ for some }x,y,z\in\mathbb{Q}.$$
Because $b\notin\mathbb{Q}$, we must have $z\neq0$. Now "complete the square" and do some rearranging to produce an $a$ satisfying an equation of the necessary form.

For the last claim, observe that $\sqrt{rs^2}=s\sqrt{r}$.

Comment: Could you please explain why if $b \neq \Bbb{Q}, z \neq 0$?

Comment: @rakhil11: First, note that you should write `\notin` ($\large\notin$), not `\neq` ($\large\neq$). Second, I recommend that you think about that for yourself some more. Remember that $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Right, yes, I meant $b \notin \Bbb{Q}$. So since $b \notin \Bbb{Q}$, $b \neq 0$. Then is your reasoning that since $-x \in \Bbb{Q}$, $-x \neq yb$, so we need the $b^2$ term to have a quadratic equation so as to have roots for this quadratic equation?